# How to check multiple id_rsa keys in ubuntu before git pull

Tags: ssh, git, github

I have two different id_rsa keys which are as follows:

```
/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_1 
/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_2
```

I have added both in ssh, and the result of ssh-add -l is as follows:

```
4096 cb:c2:9e:06:d7:e4:16:e3:dc:9b:c4:df:2f:58:30:82 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_1 (RSA)
4096 bd:a1:0f:c2:bc:4d:6f:43:0a:15:0b:39:ce:0d:08:54 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_2 (RSA)
```

Now, when I try to git pull from my repo, it is supposed to work using id_rsa_2. But it doesn't.

However, if I add the id_rsa_2 first, which gives the following result on ssh-add -l :

```
4096 cb:c2:9e:06:d7:e4:16:e3:dc:9b:c4:df:2f:58:30:82 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_2 (RSA)
4096 bd:a1:0f:c2:bc:4d:6f:43:0a:15:0b:39:ce:0d:08:54 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_1 (RSA)
```

it starts to work.

I don't understand what change should I make so that it starts checking from both id_rsa files (irrespective of which was added first).

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

[**Update for clarification**]: The error which I receive when it doesn't work is the following:

```
git remote show origin_ssh

ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So, basically it says I do not have the access rights.

This is where my origin_ssh points:

```
git remote -v

origin_ssh      git@github.com:TestRepoOne/api.git (fetch)
origin_ssh      git@github.com:TestRepoOne/api.git (push)
```

The following code reproduce my error:

```
ssh-add -D
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_1
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2
```

And the following code resolves the error [for this particular git repo]:

```
ssh-add -D
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_1
```

So, basically it works only when id_rsa_2 is added first. [**Note for clarification**: I have added id_rsa_2 in my github remote repo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to ensure that id_rsa_2 key gets used when connecting to GitHub, while using id_rsa_1 for other things.

Edit `~/.ssh/config` and add the following:

```
Host github.com             
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_2
```

This will ensure that connections to github.com use the specified key.

---

**Update:** To use different keys for different repos with the same user name, use the following in your ssh config file:

```
Host repo1.github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_1

Host repo2.github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_2
```

And you'll need to update the remotes in your `./git/config` for each repo:

```
 [remote "origin"]
    url = "ssh://git@repo1.github.com/username/repo1.git"
```

and

```
 [remote "origin"]
    url = "ssh://git@repo2.github.com/username/repo2.git"
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26507643/1380598

Comment: Thanks amc. Actually, I am using id_rsa_1 for github as well but for a different repo [ git@github.com:TestRepoOne/engine.git ]. So the host for both is github.com. So with above config, my other repo will start to fail. Can you tell me how I can use a differnet IdentityFile for both api and engine.

Comment: @KshitijMittal see updated anwer